# How to get date with aggregation T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the total number of visit for customers and get the last visited date and nextVisited

```
SELECT 
  COUNT( VisitTracking.customerID) AS #VISIT, 
  Customers.title, 
  Customers.firstName, 
  Customers.LastName, 
  Company.companyName, 
  VisitTracking.DateVisited, 
  CONVERT(date,VisitTracking.nextVisit)AS nextVisit
FROM VisitTracking 
  INNER JOIN Customers ON VisitTracking.customerID = Customers.customerID 
  INNER JOIN Customer_Company ON Customers.customerID = Customer_Company.customerID 
  INNER JOIN Company ON Customer_Company.companyID = Company.companyID
GROUP BY 
  Customers.title, 
  Customers.firstName, 
  Customers.LastName, 
  Company.companyName,
  VisitTracking.DateVisited,
  VisitTracking.nextVisit
```

Result

```
#VISIT, title, firstName ,LastName, companyName, DateVisited, nextVisit
1,        Mr, Tom, Tom, Jedii design, 2012-11-09, 2012-11-14
2 ,       Mr, Sam, Tom, compudata, 2012-11-10, 2012-11-14
1,       Mr, Mike, Mike, compudata, 2012-11-10, 2012-11-14
1,       Mr, Mike, Mike, compudata, 2012-11-16 ,2012-11-23
1,       Mr, Ryan, Ryan, compudata, 2012-11-07 ,2012-11-09
```

Comment: Show us a table structure, and what you want as the result

Comment: In description you want last visited and next visited but in  result you have twice MR Mike so please precise your expectations. Try to remove DateVisited and nextVisit from group by and set MAX(VisitTracking.DateVisited) and MAX(CONVERT(date,VisitTracking.nextVisit)) in select.

Comment: You haven't asked a question! Please add a question, and if possible a table structure with some example data, and the problems you are having achieving the required result from the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  COUNT( VisitTracking.customerID) AS #VISIT, 
  Customers.title, 
  Customers.firstName, 
  Customers.LastName, 
  Company.companyName, 
  max(VisitTracking.DateVisited) as lastVisit, 
  max(CONVERT(date,VisitTracking.nextVisit)) AS nextVisit
FROM VisitTracking 
  INNER JOIN Customers ON VisitTracking.customerID = Customers.customerID 
  INNER JOIN Customer_Company ON Customers.customerID = Customer_Company.customerID 
  INNER JOIN Company ON Customer_Company.companyID = Company.companyID
GROUP BY 
  Customers.title, 
  Customers.firstName, 
  Customers.LastName, 
  Company.companyName
```